# Codeigniter temporary store files

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I'm uploading my files to a web storage service so I don't need to store them in my server. I want to store them in a temporary folder but also use Codeigniter's uploading class for its security validation and filename encryption.

I tried this in the config

```
$config['upload_path'] = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

$this->upload->do_upload();
```

but I get the wrong upload path error. Is it possible to upload temporary files without creating my own uploading class?

Comment: $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']; is not a path but the temporary filename created. Should be a temp folder.

Comment: I see.. so I have to upload to the tmp folder and my server will handle the rest? Like deleting the file after the script is executed?

Comment: No CI upload library assumes you want to keep the image so you need to unlink the image programmatically. You would want to read the documentation: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no built-in temporary file handling in CodeIgniter. You will have to build that yourself. It is up to you to write the logic for handling the uploaded file, manipulating/verifying it, and deleting it off of your server.

If you hold onto the path where the file gets uploaded, you can use PHP's [`unlink()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) function to delete the file after you're done verifying/manipulating it.

Comment: Thanks! Using `unlink()` at the end of my uploading script is probably what I need.